# how can i fill the some columns in datagridview when page is changed? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in page load I change the some images of buttons by using checkfunction However, when i change the index of page. page load don't be called in the program I tried the
GridView1_PageIndexChanging, GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged,GridView1_PageIndexChanged events

In codes in page load, I copied it in the events but it does not work

```
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();


        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[i];
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)gvrow.Controls[1].Controls[0];

            string feedUrl = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;



            bool res = db.CheckAddedFeeds(feedUrl, User_Name);
            if (res)
            {
                ib.ImageUrl = "~/images/delete.png";
            }

        }
```

Comment: you have to bind GridView once again in those events.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a function for binding gridview as below

```
private void BindGridView()
{ 
        // place your bind grid code here..
    DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[i];
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)gvrow.Controls[1].Controls[0];

        string feedUrl = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;



        bool res = db.CheckAddedFeeds(feedUrl, User_Name);
        if (res)
        {
            ib.ImageUrl = "~/images/delete.png";
        }

    }


}
```

call this function in your apex code behind's page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }

}
```

Handle Paging event in code behind like below

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGridView();
}
```

Hope this will help you...